# Error code R when solving design matrix (X'X)^-1

Tags: r, error, matrix

A design matrix as below for a one-way analysis of variance into R, which included below. Upon trying to obtain (X'X)^-1, got an error message "try(solve(t(X)%*%X) [1]Error in solve.default(t(X)%*%X):\n system in computationally singular: reciprocal condition number=9.25186e-18\n". Because of this error, the inference cannot be conducted using these data.
How does this happen? Any recommendation for designing future studies where inference possible?
Thanks

Design matrix X (rows):
1100000
1010000
1001000
1000100
1000010
1000001
1100000
1010000
1001000
1000100
1000010
1000001
1100000
1010000
1001000
1000100
1000010
1000001
1100000
1010000
1001000
1000100
1000010
1000001

Comment: The message is clear enough, your design matrix $X$ is rank deficient. We cannot say more without details on your regression problem.